# Using strings for network path, not mapped drive, with Shell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, shell

**QUESTION UPDATED, PLEASE SEE BELOW**

I am trying to use string variables (`exedir` - the full network drive directory of an exe file, and `inputdir` - the location of the input file argument) to launch an exe with its argument using shell in VBA.

The commented out line in the script below does not work. If I manually set the drive using a letter I can get it to work, as shown below, but the .exe and .lam input file used here are both on networked drives (the variable `comp` is the unique name of the users PC, which sets the name of the .lam input file, so the input file name is different for every user).

I'm not too familiar with the syntax and borrowed it from elsewhere. Am I missing a quotation mark or maybe have too many in the commented out row?

```
   Sub CallExeWithInput()

        Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        'Statusnum = wsh.Run(Command:="""" & exedir & """""""" & inputdir & """""", windowstyle:=1, waitonreturn:=False)
        SetCurrentDirectory "M:\path\"
        Statusnum = wsh.Run(Command:="foo.exe ""M:\path\" & comp & ".lam""", windowstyle:=1, waitonreturn:=False)

   End Sub
```

Example of exedir: `\\network\path\foo.exe`

Example of inputdir: `\\network\path\compname.lam`

Example of comp: `compname` << found using `Environ$("computername")`

I'm aware of some previous questions, having read many to get this far.

I don't want to provide the letter of the drive, and ideally want to launch the .exe with the input file using string variables to input everything. One major reason I want to only use strings, is that they can be controlled by a single variable, and when the directory changes (say with an upgrade of the .exe) it will be easy to update this script.

**UPDATE**

Following the comments kindly provided below I arrived here:

```
SetCurrentDirectory fldr
Statusnum = wsh.Run(Command:="foo.exe " & quote & inputdir & quote, windowstyle:=1, waitonreturn:=False)
```

Where `quote = chr(34)` and `fldr = \\network\path\`

Interestingly, if inputdir is defined as a path to a lettered drive (`inputdir = M:\etc`), this works. If it is to a network drive path (`inputdir = \\network\etc`), it launches but the .exe immediately crashes with an invalid floating point operation.

**How can I alter this so the input file can be provided as a network path?**

If this is not possible I will presumably need a subroutine that locates which letter the user has mapped the network drive onto in order to build my string, such as this:

```
path = ":\foo\bar\"
dim x as integer
for x = 65 to 90
    If CBool(Len(Dir(Chr(x) & path))) Then
        msgbox "It's in drive " & Chr(x)  
        exit for
    end if
next x
```

Comment: Build the command you're going to run with the shell in a variable, then look at it using the debugger. Does it look correct?

Comment: You need to know what value you're trying to achieve to compare with what you've got and know what's missing or superfluous.

Comment: @Comintern Thanks and nope, experimenting now. I'm not a fan of all of the """ syntax, but it's beginning to make more sense.

Comment: `Dim Quote as String`, `Quote = Chr(34)`, then replace the multitude of multiple quotes with `& Quote &` to make it reasonably readable. At one point, you have `""""""""` which, to my eye ends up being `"""` which is 3 double quotes in a row, which probably isn't right.

Comment: @FreeMan great suggestion, thanks

Comment: I have updated the question above with my findings using your comments. Now I just need to figure out why a path to a mapped drive will work for the input file, but a networked path will not.